# rails return data to ajax success function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have this ajax function which calls a controller method  named changeshudo

```
       $('select#weeknumber').on('change', function(event) {
          var selected_shudo = $(this).val();             
          $.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url:'/clients/changeshudo',
            data:{ week: selected_shudo},
            success: function(data){  

              },
              error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                  alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
              }   
          });
        });
```

In controller i have method

```
           def changeshudo
           @client = Client.find_by('weeknumber = ?',params[:week])             

            if @client.nil?           
           render :js => "params[:week]"
            else   
          @client = Client.find_by(weeknumber: params[:week])      
          render :js => "window.location = '#{edit_client_path(@client)}'"
        end

      end
```

if @client.nil?  is true then i want to sent the params[:week] back to the success function and redirect to new action with weeknumber set to value equals to params[:week]

i.e. if the value is not present in database then all the fields of form will be cleared with only the weeknumber value set for which you want to submit the form

below given is the dropdown on which change event ajax method is called

```
    <% if @client[:id].nil? %>   
    <%= f.select :weeknumber, options_for_select(@fmon_date ,selected: @fmon_date.last), {:include_blank => "Please select"}, class: 'form-control' %>
    <% else %>
    <%= f.select :weeknumber, options_for_select(@fmon_date , selected: @client[:weeknumber]), {:include_blank => "Please select"}, class: 'form-control' %>
    <% end %>
```

please help me to pass data from controller to ajax success method and redirect to new with value set in dropdown

Comment: It'll be much better if you make the form in your `new` a partial, and render this partial with the data you want when `@client` is nil. This is a cleaner approach and also faster.

Comment: should i keep my dropdown in a partial

Comment: Not necessary. Generally you want to put it in a partial if it's used by different actions. If not, you can keep it in your template, and just replace it with your ajax call.

Comment: Of course you can move it to a partial to organize the code better.

Comment: But when @client is nil i want to clear all the data except the dropdown value

Comment: You can pass whatever value you want to the partial as instance variables.